# How to make CookieBot's banner show 13 months for _ga cookie with GTM? (GDPR)

Tags: cookies, google-tag-manager

With the new GDPR Compliance for Europe, the cookie consent should be renewed after 13 months. It is the case with CookieBot's cookie CookieConsent SaaS solution (12 months).

However CookieBot banner shows that the `_ga` cookie has a 2 years expiration (> 13 months!), even though I have set it to 13 month using GTM (Google Tag Manager), before the fist scan of CookieBot.

Indeed when I look at the `_ga` cookie expiration time from the browser, it is 13 months.

Here is what I did with GTM (I followed [this](https://www.formations-analytics.com/google-tag-manager-google-analytics-et-rgpd)):

1. Create `cookie _ga` variable, type "1st Party Cookie", Cookie Name =
   `_ga`
2. Create `get_gaCookieExpiration13Months` variable, type "Custom
   JavaScript", returning expiration time.
3. Create `Google Analytics
   Settings` variable, of type "Google Analytics Settings", with Fields to
   Set `cookieExpires = {{get_gaCookieExpiration13Months}}`

The code and configuration does set the `_ga` cookie duration to a bit less than 13 months (checked in Chrome). So this part is working.

Any idea how to have CookieBot display 13 months instead of 2 years?

Comment: I think CookieBot applies the duration of the cookie based on the "owner" of that cookie. In this case Google itself. Why would you configure this in the tool since it is already solved with GTM?

Comment: @M. Kooi: Thanks. The GDPR says 13 months, so if 2 years are displayed that is an issue, even if the duration will really be 13 months because of our GTM's configuration.

Comment: Could you provide me with a link where the GDPR says 13 months?

Comment: @M. Kooi: very good question! I was not able to find the 13 months issue in English. Just in French: https://www.cnil.fr/fr/cookies-traceurs-que-dit-la-loi.

The CNIL (French organization) recommends limit cookie duration to 13 months. It could therefore only be the CNIL's recommendation, not GDPR.

Confirmation here, page 9: https://www.iabeurope.eu/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/20171128-Working_Paper03_Consent.pdf
"For example, the French data protection authority considers that tracking cookies may only be stored for 13 months before they should expire"

Comment: Ah that's why I did'nt know about the 13 months consent. I found something more understandable for me :) https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=4e7bd0f6-9f26-47f0-801d-bfb3bdace305. Thanks for sharing. Especialy for some of our french clients.